# Should I use "stringByExpandingTildeInPath" in NSString on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, filepath

Until now in iOS I have been using something along the lines of:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileNamePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.jpg"];
```

How ever it is very verbose I have seen shorter incarnations like:

```
NSString *fileNamePath =  [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/myFile.jpg"]
```

or the even shorter:

```
[@"~/Documents/myFile.jpg" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]
```

stringByExpandingTildeInPath has been in iOS since iOS 2.0 so my question is:

Is there anything wrong with the shorter incarnations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Apple may decide to change where the Documents directory is in the future. You're best to continue using the one that you currently are.

Comment: Have they changed the Documents directory since the launch of the iOS SDK? And if they did would it affect apps that have already used stringByExpandingTildeInPath?

Comment: No, they haven't (but this doesn't mean they won't). Yes it would affect apps that already do this. Using `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` also assumes that `~` is always going to point to the same place. On OS X for instance it points to the users home area instead of into the app.